# Google Sheets Return string based value from a column with multiple entries - in an order of priority

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to return a single value from a search where you prioritize the answer. eg the table below.

```
Col1    Col2
a   For All
b   For Some
c   For Some
a   For Some
a   For Few
b   For All
```

I'm trying to return For Few if it exists, For Some as a second or For All as a last resort.
I've tried to combine if & vlookup, but it returns incorrect responses when a better value is actually present since I think it's returning the first value.

e.g.

"=if(VLOOKUP(P3, P:Q, 2,0)="For Few","For Few", if(VLOOKUP(P3, P:Q, 2,0)="For Some","For Some", "etc, etc"))"
Additionally I've succesfully tried query, but it requires a helper column and row by row query and it will need to be a lot of data, so it's suboptimal.

e.g.

"=(query($A$2:$H, ""select max(H)
where B = """"""&J2&""""""
Group by H order by Max(H) Desc limit 1
label max(H) '' "",0))"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with some sorting depending on a "priority" set on the match of the values in those curly brackets. Try it and let me know:

```
=VLOOKUP(J2,SORT(A2:B,INDEX(IFNA(MATCH(B2:B,{"For few","For some","For all"},0),4)),1),2,0)
```